# NSObject and TableView calling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsobject

In viewDidLoad, I have this code:

```
ProvRec *provRec = [[ProvRec alloc]init];
provRec.status = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)
                            ];
provRec.desc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,4)
                            ];
[listOfItems addObject:provRec];
```

How should I call to display these record in TableView in 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is by implementing the [table view datasource protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  The most critical methods are as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    ProvRec *provRec = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = provRec.status;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = provRec.desc;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [listOfItems count];
}
```

There will be variation if you have more than one section in the table, or more than one tables in the view.  But this is the basic idea.